# Override __mul__ from a child class using parent implementation: leads to problems

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm trying to implement the `__mul__` method of class `C` which extends class `P`. Class `P` has an implementation of `__mul__` but that's only for elements of that type (`P() * P()`).

So in `C.__mul__` I want to implement simple multiplication for a float when the argument is float. When it's not I want to use `P.__mul__` ... but that leads to problems as in `P.__mul__` that's a `return P(something)`...

So basically the fact that they were originally of type `C` is lost after some operations.

The following code better explain the issue.

Any idea fix this?

```
class MyFloat(object):
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

  def __mul__(self, other):
    return MyFloat(self.a * other.a)

  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.a)


class MyFloatExt(MyFloat):
  def __init__(self, a):
    MyFloat.__init__(self, a)

  def __add__(self, other):
    return MyFloatExt(self.a + other.a)

  def __mul__(self, other):
    if type(other) == (int, long, float):
      return MyFloatExt(self.a * other)
    else:
      return MyFloat.__mul__(self, other)

a = MyFloatExt(0.5)
b = MyFloatExt(1.5)

c = a + b
print c

d = a * b
print d

e = d * c
print e

print isinstance(e, MyFloat)
f = e * 0.5
print f
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you your typecheck in `__mul__` for `MyFloatExt` should look like

```
isinstance(other,(int,long,float))
```

or even better

```
isinstance(other,Number) #from numbers import Number
```

Also you would like to change definition of `__mul__` in `MyFloat` to this:

```
class MyFloat(object):
#...
  def __mul__(self, other):
    return type(self)(self.a * other.a)
#...
```

so it can create instances of your actual type

And you can prefer call `super` instead of calling `MyFloat.__mul__` with reasons of evolution your type hierarchies.

full source:

```
from numbers import Number
class MyFloat(object):
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

  def __mul__(self, other):
    return type(self)(self.a * other.a)

  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.a)


class MyFloatExt(MyFloat):
  def __init__(self, a):
    super(MyFloatExt,self).__init__(a)

  def __add__(self, other):
    return type(self)(self.a + other.a)

  def __mul__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other,Number):
      return type(self)(self.a * other)
    else:
      return super(MyFloatExt,self).__mul__(other)


a = MyFloatExt(0.5)
b = MyFloatExt(1.5)

c = a + b
print c

d = a * b
print d


e = d * c
print e

print isinstance(e, MyFloat)

f = e * 0.5
print f

print map(type,[a,b,c,d,e,f]) == [MyFloatExt]*6
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here

1. In your `__mul__` implementation of `MyFloatExt` you're never checking if `other` is an instance of `MyFloatExt`
2. `isinstance(e, MyFloat)` will always be true, because `MyFloatExt` inherits from `MyFloat`

To fix it:

```
def __mul__(self, other):

    # check if we deal with a MyFloatExt instance
    if isinstance(other, MyFloatExt):
        return MyFloatExt(self.a * other.a)

    if type(other) == (int, long, float):
        return MyFloatExt(self.a * other)

    else:
        return MyFloat.__mul__(self, other)

# do the correct check
print isinstance(e, MyFloatExt)
```